# How To Run kubectl apply commands in terraform

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have developed a terraform script to create a k8 cluster on GKE.

Post successful creation of cluster, I have set of yaml files to be applied on k8 cluster.

How can I invoke the below command in my terraform script?

```
kubectl create <.yaml>
```

Answer (score 55):

You can use the Terraform `kubectl` third party provider. Follow the installation instructions here: [Kubectl Terraform Provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/gavinbunney/kubectl/latest/docs#installation)

Then simply define a `kubectl_manifest` pointing to your YAML file like:

```
# Get your cluster-info
data "google_container_cluster" "my_cluster" {
  name     = "my-cluster"
  location = "us-east1-a"
}

# Same parameters as kubernetes provider
provider "kubectl" {
  load_config_file       = false
  host                   = "https://${data.google_container_cluster.my_cluster.endpoint}"
  token                  = "${data.google_container_cluster.my_cluster.access_token}"
  cluster_ca_certificate = "${base64decode(data.google_container_cluster.my_cluster.master_auth.0.cluster_ca_certificate)}"
}

resource "kubectl_manifest" "my_service" {
    yaml_body = file("${path.module}/my_service.yaml")
}
```

This approach has the big advantage that everything is obtained dynamically and does not rely on any local config file (very important if you run Terraform in a CI/CD server or to manage a multicluster environment).

**Multi-object manifest files**

The `kubectl` provider also offers data sources that help to handle files with multiple objest very easily. From the docs [kubectl_filename_list](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/gavinbunney/kubectl/latest/docs/data-sources/kubectl_filename_list):

```
data "kubectl_filename_list" "manifests" {
    pattern = "./manifests/*.yaml"
}

resource "kubectl_manifest" "test" {
    count = length(data.kubectl_filename_list.manifests.matches)
    yaml_body = file(element(data.kubectl_filename_list.manifests.matches, count.index))
}
```

**Extra points**: You can templatize your `yaml` files. I interpolate the cluster name in the multi-resource autoscaler yaml file as follows:

```
resource "kubectl_manifest" "autoscaler" {
  yaml_body = templatefile("${path.module}/autoscaler.yaml", {cluster_name = var.cluster_name })
}
```

Comment: I would like to use this in terraform cloud but the `kubectl` provider isn't published  to the registry hence it fails. How can I overcome this?

Comment: Current version is to use `token = data.google_client_config.default.access_token` - see https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/d/client_config.html

Comment: @Shawlz just add provider definition:
```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.13.3"

  required_providers {
    kubectl = {
      source  = "gavinbunney/kubectl"
      version = ">= 1.7.0"
    }
    
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems to only work for single-object manifests. Won't work if there's more than object event when split by `---`.

Comment: @ChristopherMarkieta, the provider handles correctly multiple objects but you have to split them first using the `kubectl_filename_list` data. See the example above. I also updated the links.

Comment: Note that kubectl provider doesn't support List resource.

Answer (score 14):

There are a couple of ways to achieve what you want to do.

You can use the Terraform resources *template_file* and *null_resource*.
Notice that I'm using the *trigger* to run the *kubectl* command always you modify the template (you may want to replace create with apply).

```
data "template_file" "your_template" {
  template = "${file("${path.module}/templates/<.yaml>")}"
}

resource "null_resource" "your_deployment" {
  triggers = {
    manifest_sha1 = "${sha1("${data.template_file.your_template.rendered}")}"
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "kubectl create -f -<<EOF\n${data.template_file.your_template.rendered}\nEOF"
  }
}
```

But maybe the best way is to use the [Kubernetes provider](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/kubernetes/).
There are two ways to configure it:

- By default your manifests will be deployed in your current context ( `kubectl config current-context` )
- The second way is to statically define TLS certificate credentials:

```
provider "kubernetes" {
  host = "https://104.196.242.174"

  client_certificate     = "${file("~/.kube/client-cert.pem")}"
  client_key             = "${file("~/.kube/client-key.pem")}"
  cluster_ca_certificate = "${file("~/.kube/cluster-ca-cert.pem")}"
}
```

Once done that, you can create your own deployment pretty easy. For a basic pod, it'd be something as easy as:

```
resource "kubernetes_pod" "hello_world" {
  metadata {
    name = "hello-world"
  }

  spec {
    container {
      image = "my_account/hello-world:1.0.0"
      name  = "hello-world"
    }

    image_pull_secrets  {
      name = "docker-hub"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me with null_resource and local exec. `exit status 1. Output: << was unexpected at this time.`

Comment: Christopher, I'd need to see your code to be able to tell you what was the problem.

Comment: My code is literally your code. The only difference is I filled in the named yaml file and that file definitely exists and work `data "template_file" "your_template" {
  template = "${file("${path.module}/templates/ingress.yaml")}"
}`

Comment: I can run kubectl apply -f filepath/templates/ingress.yml both in terraform and locally no problem. The issue is with the EOF and rendering the file business.

Comment: Copy the content of your ingress.yaml file, open a terminal, write kubectl apply -f -<<EOF , press enter, paste your code, press enter again, write EOF and press enter.
Let me know if that works. It may be an issue with your OS. With local-exec you are basically executing a command as you'd do in your terminal, so if something works on it, it should work in the same way on Terraform.

Comment: Thank you, changing the interpreter to bash fixed the issue, for anyone on windows you need. `command = "cat <<EOF\n${template}\nEOF | kubectl apply -f-"

interpreter = ["bash"]"`

Comment: It turns out that did not work! It looks like it works, but it does not actually apply anything.

Answer (score 1):

When creating multiple Terraform resources, it is usually better to use named resource instances than to use a list (`count`). If the source file is updated and the order of Kubernetes resources change, it may cause Terraform to delete/create resources just because of the index change.  This code creates a key by concatenating `kind` and `metadata.name` fields:

```
data "kubectl_file_documents" "myk8s" {
  content = file("./myk8s.yaml")
}

resource "kubectl_manifest" "myk8s" {
  # Create a map of { "kind--name" => raw_yaml }
  for_each  = {
    for value in [
      for v in data.kubectl_file_documents.myk8s.documents : [yamldecode(v), v]
    ] : "${value.0["kind"]}--${value.0["metadata"]["name"]}" => value.1
  }
  yaml_body = each.value
}
```

In the future you may want to use Hashicorp's official [kubernetes_manifest resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/resources/manifest) instead (as of 2.5.0 -- in beta, buggy):

```
resource "kubernetes_manifest" "default" {
  for_each = {
    for value in [
      for yaml in split(
        "\n---\n",
        "\n${replace(file("./myk8s.yaml"), "/(?m)^---[[:blank:]]*(#.*)?$/", "---")}\n"
      ) :
      yamldecode(yaml)
      if trimspace(replace(yaml, "/(?m)(^[[:blank:]]*(#.*)?$)+/", "")) != ""
    ] : "${value["kind"]}--${value["metadata"]["name"]}" => value
  }
  manifest = each.value
}
```

Comment: works for me with kubernetes_manifest as of kubernetes provider 2.11.0

Comment: this has been removed from latest Kubernetes provider

Comment: @madduci what was removed?

Comment: you can't provide the "manifest" field in the "kubernetes_manifest" resouce

Answer (score 1):

Adding some more information to existing answers for 2022 viewers. Given question is missing information about where these terraform & kubectl command are need to be executed

**Case 1: Developer is using a local system that is not part of Google Cloud Platform**
In this case, when you are using `null_resource` to execute a command then your command will run in you local pc not in google cloud.

**Case 2: Developer is using a system that is part of Google Cloud Platform like Google Console Terminal or Google Cloud Code**

In this case, when you are using `null_resource` to execute a command then your command will run in a temporary environment that is actively managed google cloud.

From here, it is possible to execute `kubectl` command using terraform. Said that, next question is it a good approach to do? It's not.

GCP is not a free resource. If you are building/using tools, it is important to use the right tool for right resource. In DevOps operations, there are two core areas. One is setting up infra where **Terraform** works best and next is managing infra where **Ansible** works best. For the same reason, GCP actively provide support for these.

Answer (score 0):

The answers here are great.  One suggestion as your requirements evolve from the initial manifest, you may want to look at creating a helm chart from the the manifest (or maybe one already exists) and use the terraform helm provider instead to set the values for your environment.

https://tech.paulcz.net/blog/getting-started-with-helm/

You'll notice an advantage to helm provider is that is easy to override and manage changes in values by terraform environment instead of embedding it into the manifest.

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/helm/latest/docs/resources/release

Answer (score 0):

In case for the remote url hosting the yaml file, and the yaml file has included multiple configs/objects, here's what can be done.

```
resource "null_resource" "controller_rancher_installation" {

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOT
      echo "Downloading rancher config"
      curl -L https://some-url.yaml -o rancherconfig.yaml
    EOT
  }
}

data "kubectl_path_documents" "rancher_manifests" {
    pattern = "./rancherconfig.yaml"
    depends_on = [null_resource.controller_rancher_installation]
}

resource "kubectl_manifest" "spot_cluster_controller" {
    count     = length(data.kubectl_path_documents.spot_controller_manifests.documents)
    yaml_body = element(data.kubectl_path_documents.spot_controller_manifests.documents, count.index)
}
```

The idea is to download it firstly, and then apply it. This is based on observation:

1. `pattern = "./rancherconfig.yaml"` doesn't support remote url, only
   local files.
2. `"kubectl_manifest"` by default only applies the first
   config/object in the yaml file.

Comment: This doesn't work if you include kubectl in your eks module

Answer (score 0):

You can also also use the helm provider together with the itscontained chart. For example, the tekton dashboard could be installed like this, building on Yuri's Yaml splitting expression:

```
data "http" "tekton_dashboard_install" {
  url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/tekton-releases/dashboard/previous/v0.26.0/tekton-dashboard-release.yaml"

  request_headers = {
    Accept = "application/octet-stream"
  }
}

locals {
  tekton_dashboard_manifests = [
    for yaml in split(
      "\n---\n",
      "\n${replace(data.http.tekton_dashboard_install.body, "/(?m)^---[[:blank:]]*(#.*)?$/", "---")}\n"
    ) :
    yamldecode(yaml)
    if trimspace(replace(yaml, "/(?m)(^[[:blank:]]*(#.*)?$)+/", "")) != ""
  ]
}

resource "helm_release" "tekton_dashboard" {
  name       = "tekton_dashboard"
  repository = "https://charts.itscontained.io"
  chart      = "raw"
  version    = "0.2.5"
  namespace  =  "tekton-pipelines"

  values = [
    yamlencode({ resources = local.tekton_dashboard_manifests })
  ]
}
```

Some YAML files like the tekton core file come with a namespace definition, which must be filtered out first. Which is easy after the YAML is parsed.

This solution avoids the "Provider produced inconsistent result after apply" problems with the kubernetes_manifest resources and the hacky workarounds that follow.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommand alway using kubectl_path_documents.

if the yaml file contains more than object event when split by ---, you have to use kubectl_path_documents, this is not only for loading multiple yaml files but also handle the multiple objects when split by --- in one yaml.

data "kubectl_path_documents" "metrics_server_yaml" {
// somehow pattern only supports search in local file directory, not from remote url.
pattern = "${path.module}/yamls/metrics-server.yaml"
}

resource "kubectl_manifest" "metrics_server_manifests" {
count     = length(data.kubectl_path_documents.metrics_server_yaml.documents)
yaml_body = element(data.kubectl_path_documents.metrics_server_yaml.documents, count.index)
}

if you need to load the yaml for https url, you can run "curl" in a null_resource .

Answer (score -1):

You can use terraform local-exec to do this.

```
   resource "aws_instance" "web" {
     # ...
     provisioner "local-exec" {
      command = "echo ${aws_instance.web.private_ip} >> private_ips.txt"
     }
   }
```

Ref: https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/local-exec.html

Comment: This would be a better example if you actually included the command the question included instead of being a copy-paste of the example in the docs. Also if you formatted it with `terraform fmt`.

Answer (score -11):

The best way would be to use the [Kubernetes](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/kubernetes/index.html) provider of Terraform

Comment: This answer would be better if you provided a simple, worked example rather than just linking to the Kubernetes provider docs.

Comment: with current version of kubernetes provider there is no way to apply .yaml file. see https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-kubernetes/issues/141