# How to use yaml file in Terraform?

Tags: yaml, terraform, azure-aks, terraform-provider-azure

I have kubernetes configuration in a seperate yaml file. I want to use that yaml file while running terraform can I do it? If yes, then how.

Comment: What do you mean by the kubernetes configuration YAML file?

Comment: the file that includes all the kubernetes config.. info about the pods,services etc.

Comment: If like that, I think you can use the `null_resource` to execute the `kubectl` command locally.

Comment: Yes, now i am making use of null_resource for this. Also i had a question. If i am using kubectl apply -f commands and then terraform apply , it applies it to the environment. 

But when i want to destroy the creation, what do i do?? keep the same command and then perform terraform destroy or change the command to kubectl delete -f and then terraform apply??

Comment: Yes, change to the command `kubectl delete -f`. And do you mind mark it if I add an answer to display the suggestions?

Comment: I know i can use kubectl delete -f but i am using more than one null_resource,and i cant change from kubectl apply to kubectl delete for every null_resource. Is there any other way?

Comment: You can see the [Kubernetes in Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/kubernetes/guides/getting-started.html), it supports multiple resources in a sperate way and cannot load all the configurations from the YAML file.

Comment: I am making use of null_resource to load all the .yaml config files in terraform. so I asked what should I do  if there are many null_resource in my code? Is using `kubectl apply -f` and then `terraform apply` to create and `terraform destroy` to destroy, the correct way??

Comment: Yes, the terraform destroy will delete all the things you have deployed.

Comment: Any more questions? Do you solve the problem?

Comment: yes, It worked.

Comment: Well, do you mind if I add an answer and you accept it?

Comment: Is there anything unexpected in the answer? I didn't see any updates and you also didn't accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my experience, Terraform supports the Kubernetes provider, but all the things in that provider are separate, such as deployment, pod, service and etc. It does not provide a way to load all the things from a configuration file.

So, to deploy from the configuration file, I recommend you put the `kubectl apply -f config_file` in the [`null_resource`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/null/resource.html). And it's also simple to delete all the things that have deployed with multiple mull_resource, you just need to use the Terraform command `terraform destroy`, it will remove all the resources that deployed through the Terraform file.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can, but you have to use 3rd-part kubernetes provider

```
# Retrieve an access token as the Terraform runner
data "google_client_config" "provider" {}

# Same parameters as kubernetes provider
data "google_container_cluster" "my-cluster" {
  name      = "my-cluster"
  location  = "europe-west4-a"
}

provider "kubectl" {
  load_config_file       = false
  host                   = "https://${google_container_cluster.my-cluster.endpoint}"
  cluster_ca_certificate = "${base64decode(google_container_cluster.my-cluster.master_auth.0.cluster_ca_certificate)}"
  token = data.google_client_config.provider.access_token
}

data "kubectl_filename_list" "manifests" {
    pattern = "./manifests/*.yml"
}

resource "kubectl_manifest" "test" {
    count     = length(data.kubectl_filename_list.manifests.matches)
    yaml_body = file(element(data.kubectl_filename_list.manifests.matches, count.index))
}
```

Link to provider
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/gavinbunney/kubectl/latest/docs

Similar question
[How To Run kubectl apply commands in terraform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54094575/how-to-run-kubectl-apply-commands-in-terraform)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know this has been talked about for quite some time but as of yet hasn't been implemented: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-kubernetes/issues/141

If it helps, I often use this tool to convert YAML files to terraform specification. It is quite reliable. https://github.com/sl1pm4t/k2tf

Comment: Can you provide me any documentation that lets us know how to install it on windows. ? @Karl

Comment: I use Linux. You can find the binaries for all supported operating systems here https://github.com/sl1pm4t/k2tf/releases/tag/v0.4.1

Answer (score 2):

To answer to the original question specifically, which tags contain `Azure` and `AKS`, as well as the asker is requesting to use pure `kubernetes yaml manifests` in `terraform` - I've used `gavinbunney/kubectl`:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {

    kubectl = {
      source  = "gavinbunney/kubectl"
      version = "1.14.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "kubectl" {
  load_config_file = false
  host = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.REDACTED.kube_config.0.host
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.REDACTED.kube_config.0.cluster_ca_certificate)
  token = yamldecode(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.REDACTED.kube_config_raw).users[0].user.token
}
```

More info could be found in the [original topic in Github](https://github.com/gavinbunney/terraform-provider-kubectl/issues/35)